# How to customize or reprogram function of specific keys on my keyboard and the LED on my laptop

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, io

When I disable bluetooth on my laptop, the light does not go off and the blinking of the Wi-Fi LED is starting to bother me. Since I sometimes use my laptop in a poor lighting condition an illuminated keyboard would be pretty cool.

I am seriously considering to make some modification to my laptop and due to its location, I think that the LED from Wi-Fi, capslock and power would be sufficient to provide enough amount of light for my occasional glances to my keyboard. And while I find it challenging, the following are my attempts to frame the questions:

- Where can I find resources to study & explore the possibility of reprogramming the function of certain specific keys? For instance, I would like to be able to press <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> and <kbd>Return</kbd> on my keyboard to activate certain LED to be used to slightly illuminate my keyboard.
- Are there any command line ways to identify the simple output such as LED that are comparable to the `ls` command? I suspect that it can't be too far off from how the machine talks to the fan or the heat measurement done quite gracefully.
- Is there any simple or awesome hack to give my keyboard a back light? The USB led light that I've been using almost damaged my USB port on several occasions and solving this would give me peace of mind while providing a good excuse for me to get ever more up close and personal with my Linux.

This is sort of a continuation of my previous question (https://askubuntu.com/q/409306/228497) as they are some of the things that have been tickling my curiosity.

Comment: You don't say if you are working in console mode or under X (graphical interface).

Comment: You are most likely using X but each desktop manager KDE/Gnome/xfce all use different ways to assign keyboard short cuts. What desktop manager are you using?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in a single post. Break this up into three separate questions and post each by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the state of the keyboard leds with the [`setleds`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setleds) command (part of the console-tools utility suite). Unless you're logged into a text mode console, you'll need to run that command as root. There's no way that I know of to do this with X11 tools — in theory X11 has this functionality but [the implementation seems to be broken in Xorg](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49276).

```
setleds -L +num +caps +scroll </dev/console
```